# How do I prevent regex from starting over after certain characters?

Tags: regex, re2

I am attempting to write a regular expression that matches on strings that match a valid email address format. However, I want the regex to not match when the email address is preceded by certain key words (let's say "blern" for this example). Unfortunately, this regex will be implemented in RE2, so negative look-behinds aren't an option.

I've managed to accomplish this task partially using the regex below, but I'm having another issue: When the email address matches the valid format, the regex matches and it is redacted:

sambranson@gmail.com = xxxxxxxxxx

And when the keyword appears at the start, it does not match and is thus not redacted:

blernsambranson@gmail.com = blernsambranson@gmail.com

But when the keyword is followed by a slash, the keyword is not redacted, but the rest of the address is:

blern/sambranson@gmail.com = blern/xxxxxxxx

I'm trying to fix my existing regex so that this does not happen, and even when a / is present the entire email address is not redacted. This also occurs with a . and - character.

Edit: removed incorrect explanation for the problem

Existing Regex:

`\b([A-Zac-z0-9]|b[A-Za-km-z0-9]|bl[A-Za-df-z0-9]|ble[A-Za-qs-z0-9]|bler[A-Za-mo-z0-9)[A-Za-z0-9._-]*[A-Za-z0-9-]@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\b`

Comment: ```\``` and `.` don't tell the regex engine that the string is over. It stops matching because those characters aren't present in your pattern so it has to stop.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution. How about first searching for your blocking string using simple substring search, and then applying a much simpler matching regex to the substring that precedes the blocking string?

Comment: @CAustin, I've added / and . into the regex as below, but I'm still seeing the same behavior. 

\b([A-Zac-z0-9]|b[A-Za-km-z0-9]|bl[A-Za-df-z0-9]|ble[A-Za-qs-z0-9]|bler[A-Za-mo-z0-9)[A-Za-z0-9/._-]*[A-Za-z0-9-]@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\b

Comment: @joanis I'm relatively new to regex and I'm not sure how to execute what you're describing. Would you be willing to elaborate?

Comment: @B.Allred I'd need to know what programming language you are using, first... The regex would be yours starting after the bit to exclude `blern`, but substring find and extraction will come from the standard llibraries of your programming language.

Comment: Since re2 seems to be a C++ library, `string::find()` and `string::substr()` might be the relevant functions.

Comment: Yes, this is not the type of thing that you want to do entirely with a single regex pattern, especially if you're using RE2. Please explain which programming language or tool you're using for better context.

Comment: The regex's I've been working on are rules that are being implemented in Cloudera sensitive data redaction. I'm relatively new to this software, but there isn't a way I'm aware of to programmatically obtain substrings as is being described here.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by first searching for your blocking string using simple substring search, and then applying a regex only to the substring that precedes the blocking string.

Assuming this is done in C++, here is some pseudo code for that solution. I'm not setup to compile C++ at the moment, so you'll have to finalize the work and get it to compile, or convert it for the language you are working with if it's not C++. (I'm assuming C++ since `re2` seems to be a C++ library.)

```
std::string s = "sambranson@gmail.com = blernsambranson@gmail.com";
std::string stop = "blern";
// set sub to the part of s before stop, or to all of s if stop does not occur:
std::string sub = s.substr(0, s.find(stop));

// now apply re to sub instead of s
// your RE, after removing the "blern" exclusion parts, should do what you want:
// \b[A-Za-z0-9._-]*[A-Za-z0-9-]@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\b
```